# If table have 0 rows exit procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a procedure inside a package and I want to implement a logic, wich will not insert the temp table into the main table if the temp table have 0 rows, and then go to the next procedure of the package.

```
IF (not exists(select 1 from temp)) THEN
   RETURN;
ELSE
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE main';
   INSERT --+APPEND 
          INTO main
          Select * from temp;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE temp';
END IF;
```

With this solution, the package is compiled with error.

Can anyone give me some tips?

Comment: Please provide the error message.  Are you sure that main and temp have the same columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest is to use a variable to check:

```
--- suggested edit: add condition to select 1 row at most and avoid
--  counting big table.
select count(1) into v_count from temp where rownum <=1;

IF (v_count=0) THEN
   RETURN;
ELSE
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE main';
   INSERT --+APPEND 
          INTO main
          Select * from temp;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE temp';
END IF;
```

Comment: What if the table has a million rows? The code will waste a lot of time and resources getting an exact count it doesn't need. Why not limit the count to 1 row with a "where rownum = 1" clause? Also the standard expression is "count(*)", not "count(1)", you don't need brackets around IF conditions, and your caps lock is on.

Comment: Personaly I would be a bit carefull with using `SELECT INTO` like this, if your table `temp` is already empty you will end up with a `ORA-01403: no data found` error. And those can be hard to find if you have a bigger database.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson. Nice optimization from Tenzin suggest, we should try `rownum <= 1`?

Answer (score 1):

you can use loop, without any variables, just first iteration, something like this

```
FOR a in (select 1 from temp where rownum = 1) LOOP

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE main';
   INSERT --+APPEND 
          INTO main
          Select * from temp;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE temp';

END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just count one row and then test whether the result is 0 or 1:

```
declare
    l_row_check integer := 0;
begin
    select count(*) into l_row_check from main
    where  rownum = 1;

    if l_row_check = 0 then
        execute immediate 'truncate table main';

        insert --+ append 
        into main
        select * from temp;

        execute immediate 'truncate table temp';
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Some answer on here use a `SELECT INTO` method, but I find those a bit tricky. 
Since if for example `SELECT ColumnA INTO vcColumnA FROM Temp` will not have any records, you will end up with the error `ORA-01403: no data found`. 
And those can be hard to find if you have a bigger database.

To loop through a table and do something with values I think cursors and records are more safe. 
For example:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR cTemp IS 
        SELECT  ColumnA, ColumnB 
        FROM    Temp;

    rTemp   cTemp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN cTemp;
    LOOP
        FETCH cTemp INTO rTemp;
        -- Exit when we read all lines in the Temp table. 
        EXIT WHEN cTemp%NOTFOUND;

        --Do something with every row. 
        --For example, print ColumnB. 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rTemp.ColumnB);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE cTemp;
END;
/
```

Comment: Well, if you're going to use an explicit cursor then you don't need to loop. Just fetch once and check `%found`.

Comment: True, if you only expect one row back you don't need the loop part. Tehn we can just use  open cursor, fetch and then close.